# Converting decimal to base 2-16 without using String (Java)

Tags: java

I am writing a program to convert a base 10 integer to any base 2-16. Here are the terms:

"The method is to convert the decimal value the user selected into whatever base the user selected and print the converted value one place value at a time by using an index into an array of characters 0-9 amd A-F that is initialized to contain those characters.
In the method you will find the largest place value (i.e. power of the base) that will divide into the decimal number. 
Then you can set up a loop that will operate from that power down to and including the 0th power to determine how many times each place value goes into the decimal number. Using the loop counter, index into the character array to print the character that corresponds to the quotient number and then subtract the product of the place value and the quotient from the decimal number. With the power (loop index) decreased, repeat until you finish the 0th place value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConvertIt
{//start program
public static void main(String[] args)
{//start main
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a positive integer from 0 to 10000.");
int number = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the base to convert to.");
int base = input.nextInt();

convertIt(number, base);

}//end main

public static void convertIt(int number, int base)
{//start method
int array = {0123456789ABCDEF};

while (number != 0)
{//start while

}//end while
for (int i = array.length-1; i > -1; i--)
{//start for

}//end for

}//end while
}//end method
}//end program
```

I think I have it set up correctly, I'm just not sure how to attack it. I understand the concept of what I'm doing, just not the execution of it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConvertIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer from 0 to 10000.");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the base to convert to.");
        int base = input.nextInt();

        input.close();

        convertIt(number, base);

    }

    public static void convertIt(int number, int base) {

        if ( base <= 1 || base > 16)
            return;

        char[] array = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A',
                'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        String convertedNum = "";

        do {
            convertedNum += array[number % base];
            number = number / base;
        } while (number != 0);

        convertedNum = new StringBuilder(convertedNum).reverse().toString();
        System.out.println(convertedNum);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** At first I didn't catch that you wanted to do this without using string. So I try to provide a solution to this as well, but I think it's kind of messy. I would have personally preferred using a string instead, maybe because I don't know how to store those values in a cleaner way.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConvertIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer from 0 to 10000.");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the base to convert to.");
        int base = input.nextInt();

        input.close();

        convertIt(number, base);

    }

    public static void convertIt(int number, int base) {

        if (base <= 1 || base > 16)
            return;

        char[] array = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A',
                'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        ArrayList<Integer> converted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // convert the number
        do {
            converted.add(number % base);
            number = number / base;
        } while (number != 0);

        int count = converted.size() - 1;
        int temp;
        // revert the numbers
        for (int i = (count - 1) >> 1; i < 0; --i) {
            temp = converted.get(i);
            converted.set(i, converted.get(count - i));
            converted.set(count - i, temp);
        }

        // print the numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < converted.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(array[converted.get(i)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.floor` is redundant since `number/base` is already an integer

Comment: Not in my code though. Let's say `number` is `1234` and `base` is `8`, then `number / base = 154.25`.

Comment: Yes in your code though. `number` is an integer; `base` is an integer; `number/base` is an integer whose value is `154`. Integer division. `number /= base` would have done just as well. You also need a `do/while,` not a `while,` otherwise you return an empty string if the input is zero.

Comment: This is only some code I did on top of my head at the moment, sure it's cleaner ways of doing it.

Comment: @Bjørn Bråthen why not just traverse the array backwards like `for (int i = converted.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            System.out.print(array[converted.get(i)]);
        }`

Comment: @CSnerd That's a better solution of course. He did ask about printing the numbers after all.